# Using UNIX, how to display a count of the processes on my system?

Tags: unix

Can any one please tell me how can I display a count of the processes on my system in a form like `count process_name`

Comment: and what system is that?

Comment: my shell is Bash. I am using Ubuntu. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ps aux | wc -l

or I think it's summarized in "top"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I didn't thought about it before. that was very helpful.